# os.system error: process not found "video.mp4"

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.system

> I am having trouble finding a way to close a video tab with the os library.
> I get the following error when i try `os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM video.mp4')` to close the video .

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os 
import time 


msg = 'random text'
language = 'en'

obj = gTTS(text=msg, lang=language, slow=False)

obj.save('video.mp4')


os.system('video.mp4')
time.sleep(3)
os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM video.mp4')
```

Comment: `video.mp4` seems to be a file name, not an executable. Have you checked what the actual process name is, i.e. the program that is being run?

Comment: What error are you getting? That will probably give you a clue to your problem. Hint: /IM requires an image name so you should check to see which application is associated with MP4 files on your system - possibly wmplayer.exe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`video.mp4` is the file name. `TASKKILL` is used to end running applications and `video.mp4` is not an application, it is the file opened by the application. You can learn more about TASKKILL from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill).

If you have not changed your default media player in windows, it will be opened with Windows Media Player and to kill it, you can use replace this

```py
os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM video.mp4')
```

with this

```py
os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM wmplayer.exe')
```

or else, the best option for you is

```py
# install playsound with the command below
# pip install playsound
from playsound import playsound

# Your code
from gtts import gTTS
import os 
import time 
msg = 'random text'
language = 'en'
obj = gTTS(text=msg, lang=language, slow=False)

# Saving as .mp3 or .mav is the best for playaudio
obj.save('video.mp3')

# Play the saved sound with python
playsound('video.mp3')


# NOTE: This is not how you should sort your imports
# 1 -  standard library imports; 2 - related third party imports; 3 - local application/library specific imports; all in alphebetical order
```

You can find more alteratives to `playsound` from [here](https://pythonbasics.org/python-play-sound/) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/play-sound-in-python/). but `playsound` is the most easy and simple method.